# Does "Resident Set Size" is the same as windows “SetProcessWorkingSetSize”?

Tags: linux, api, ubuntu, memory-management, memory-leaks

I could control a memory leak on a specific program by setting her `Max working Set Size` on windows.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setprocessworkingsetsize

Does someone know how I could do the same on Linux as the program has the same memory leak on both OS.

Using `Ubuntu 20.04`.

Does `Resident Set Size` is the same as windows `SetProcessWorkingSetSize`?
Is ever possible to set a maximum on it like on windows?